# Why is recomended way to mount rabbitmq.conf and definitions.json from docker-compose to host machine when using rabbitmq official image

Tags: docker, docker-compose, rabbitmq

I have created docker-compose file that should start rabbitmq.

```
version: "2.2"
services:
  rabbitmq:
    image: "rabbitmq:<version>-alpine"
    hostname: "rabbitmq"
    container_name: "rabbitmq"
    mem_limit: "750m"
    ports:
    ...
    networks: [ "traefik" ]
    labels:
     ...
    volumes:
      - "./rabbitmq.conf:/etc/rabbitmq/conf.d/rabbitmq.conf"
      - "./definitions.json:/etc/rabbitmq/definitions.json"
      - "/setlog/rabbitmq/data:/var/lib/rabbitmq/mnesia" # data dir
    healthcheck:
      test: "rabbitmq-diagnostics -q check_running"
      interval: "20s"
      timeout: "7s"
      retries: 2
    restart: "always"

networks:
  traefik:
    external: true
```

My issue is that user of files inside of docker container is "rabbitmq" and when I do mount of this files from host machine to container as it is shown in code above, this files get new user and owner.

Can I somehow make that user outside of docker files is user "a" and that user inside of docker-container stays to be "rabbitmq" user?

Is there a way to check if it is important that user of this files is "rabbitmq" inside of docker container or not, I could not find anything in official rabbitmq docker image documentation ?

Comment: Does it matter who owns the files?  It's a read-only mount, so as long as the files are world-readable, the RabbitMQ broker will be able to read them and you won't be missing any functionality.  (The file should have the same _numeric_ ID inside the container and without, but there are two different `/etc/passwd` files that would translate this back to a user name; but this shouldn't matter in practice.)

Comment: It was my mistake I should habe removed that files are mounted as read only. I do not know if rabbitmq will work if files are mounted as read only.

Comment: Nevertheless, I'd be surprised if the RabbitMQ broker tries to write these files.  Does it work even with the "wrong" ownership?